# How to test that a type declared as "public class" is a class using java.lang.Class?

Tags: java

java.lang.Class has methods to test if a given type is:

- isAnnotation
- isArray
- isEnum
- isInterface
- isPrimitive

but how does one test that an object of type Class (`instanceof Class` is `true`) represents a declared, non-abstract class rather than in interface, enum, primitive, array, etc. For  example:

```
package org.acme;

public class ACME {

      public ACME() {

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("org.acme.ACME");
       // Expected I could use a clazz.isClass().
      }
}
```

I was looking for a isClass method, but there isn't.

---

**Update**

I see the confusion generated by my question - while some people got my question.

I did some further research and found out that in .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isclass.aspx,

there this is a isClass member and I was looking for a similar method in java.lang.Class.

I now know that the equivalent in Java is to test for all the other isXXX methods to find out that it's not a class.

Comment: Why not test `instanceof`?

Comment: @0A0D How would that help in this case?

Comment: @arshajii: Assuming he knows what `Object` he wants, he could test if the `Object` is an `instanceof` a known `Class` and operate on it.

Comment: Huh? Are you from the department of redundancy or something? If it's an instance of `Class` ... it's a class. All the methods you mention are non-static methods and members of `Class`

Comment: Do you mean `isClass` in the sense that your type is _not_ an enum, interface, etc.?  Or `isClass` in the sense that an object is of this particular type?

Comment: @0A0D It seems to me that he wants to take a `Class` and determine if it's a plain old class (not an interface, enum etc.)

Comment: @arshajii: I see, point taken.

Comment: @arshajii. Absolutely!

Comment: @Louis Wasserman. The former, i.e. not an interface, enum or etc. Just a POJO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that should work for you:

1. You can do `class instanceof Object`
2. You can check all the other `is...()` methods. If they are all false you have a class.

Answer (score 6):

It seems there's a disconnect in your question. *Everything* is a class (except primitives - the `isPrimitive()` method actually means the class is an autobox type).

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("org.acme.ACME");
// Expected I could use a clazz.isClass().
```

That would be redundant. You already know it's a class. Because you have an instance of `Class`.

It would appear that for some reason you would like to know it's not any of the *types* of classes the methods you list tell you, in which case you'd simply do a check to negate those options:

```
if (!clazz.isAnnotation() &&
    !clazz.isArray() /* && ... etc */ ) 
{

    // Not any of those things.

}
```

Comment: I'm actually kind of surprised that `Class` doesn't have such a method as `isPlainOldClass`.

Comment: @arshajii I question the utility of such a thing (and actually what I list above). Why would you ever care? But ... that wasn't the question :)

Comment: I suppose you're right. It just seems to be logical given that there are already methods to test whether the class represents an array, interface, enum and whatnot. But yes, the utility would still likely be limited.

Comment: @Brian Roach. Trying to clarify the question, how would you name a type that is none of the other isXXX types (annotation, enum, interface, etc.)? See comments. A class? A POJO? Let me know.
Concerning the utility of such a thing, let me be the judge of that.
I didn't ask this question out of the blue.

Answer (score 4):

`Class` objects are singletons. Therefore, if you have an instance of any type, you can test that it is an exact class instance using:

```
theInstance.getClass() == TheTargetClass.class
```

As to testing whether a class is a "full" class, just negate all the test you mentioned. This first test is already an efficient filter... And do not forget `.isSynthetic()`.

Comment: I think this misses the point; he wants to take a `Class` object and determine if it represents a 'regular' class, i.e. not an interface, enum etc.

Comment: And what happens if you do not know `TheTargetClass` (you need dynamically)?

Comment: @fge. Thanks, but in the real case I don't know the type, i.e. TheTargetClass.class.

Comment: @J.Gonzalez then what characteristic do you want to know exactly? There has to be _some_ filter

Comment: @fge. Thanks for your help. The question has been updated and I added some comment to clarify the question. From the answers right now one has to test that a java.lang.Class is not an interface, enum, array, etc. to find out, for a better word, that it's a Java class (POJO).

Comment: @J.Gonzalez well, as long as you have the `Class` object you can test all of that

Answer (score 3):

Not so readable but

```
object.getClass().getModifiers() < 30 //abstract classes are not included
```

or in a more readable way:

```
object.getClass().getModifiers() < Modifier.PROTECTED + Modifier.STATIC + Modifier.FINAL
```

seems to work, being more neat (but more obscure) than

```
!(!isInterface() && !isEnum() && !is ...)
```

A simple class can only have these modifiers:

```
public static final int PUBLIC           = 0x00000001;
public static final int PRIVATE          = 0x00000002;
public static final int PROTECTED        = 0x00000004;
public static final int STATIC           = 0x00000008;
public static final int FINAL            = 0x00000010;
```

while abstract, interafce, enum or annotation has larger values (over 200).

You can see the Modifiers of a class by calling `Modifier.toString(myClass.getModifiers())`. The `getModifiers()` class returns the sum in hexa of all modifiers (as I have tested on some values; the implementation is native).

Comment: Magic numbers are magic. No offense, but I'd want to strangle someone if I ever saw that.

Comment: I like the concept, and there should be no problem with extracting the code as a method so that the "magic number(s)" were localized to a single documented place.  However, this is not quite sufficient because Modifiers.XXX does not deal with arrays and primitives.

Comment: @KevinWelker If you ignore abstract classes you can use it since array and primitive classes are abstract (and final).

Comment: hmmm... didn't know that about arrays.  I just tried it for primitives though and they are *not* abstract.

Comment: @KevinWelker Running `System.out.println(Modifier.toString(int.class.getModifiers()));` prints `public abstract final` in Java 6 u 37.

Comment: I took a more roundabout way at it and got a different ressult. Declared an `int` field and used reflection to get the field by name, get it's class modifiers, and then use a JUnit assert on `Modifiers.isAbstract(m);` which failed.  I'm not sure why there is a difference but there is.  I just verified it again.  At this point it is more a curiosity, as the OP doesn't seem to be interested in primitives or arrays.

Comment: Did a little more digging into my technique: getting an `int` `Field`, and getting an instance of it means it has to autobox it into an Object, so the the returned type was `Integer`.  Mystery solved.

Comment: I overlooked the existence of `Field.getType()`, as I knew I couldn't directly call `Field.getClass()`

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution:
You can try to execute the Class's `newInstance` method. If the class is abstract or an interface an `InstantiationException` will be thrown- Otherwise, you're good.

The problem is that creating a new instance in a class you don't know might have unknown effects, or the class might not have a default constructor.